# Put Json In to Array using Gson

Tags: java, json, gson

Hello So I am writing an online translator using Yandex free tool . 
I have this program that when user clicked on btn_translate I get the from and to languages from the comboBoxes then I get the text from the text label . Sending it to the server via the curl command.
keep in mind that i'm a beginner in this field so my code can have tons of problems ...

Here is the url sample:

> https://translate.yandex.net/api/v1.5/tr.json/translate?key=API-KEY&lang=en-fa&text=hi

and here is the Json returned by the yandex:

> {"code":200,"lang":"en-fa","text":["سلام"]}

So Here is my question:
I want to access the 3rd item in this Json as you can see it is "text" how should i do that ?

i am using Gson and i don't know how to put this Json i'm receiving in to an array which is like this :

Array[0] = 200 ( Code )

Array[1] = "en-fa" ( Lang )

Array[2] = "سلام" ( text )

and here is my code ( btn pushed part ) :

```
                String command = IInfo.CMD +"&lang="+combo_from.getSelectedItem()
                        +"-"+combo_to.getSelectedItem()+"&text="+txt_word.getText();

                System.out.println(command);
                System.out.println("btn pushed");

                try(Reader reader = new InputStreamReader(
                        Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command).getInputStream()
                )){
                    JsonElement json = new JsonParser().parse(reader);
                    System.out.println(json);
                } catch (IOException e)
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
```

and if you can explain to me how my try is working it would be awesome !
thanks.

Comment: Why you are usinc curl, and not java to request, for example OkHttp or any other.
you can use `gson.fromJson()`

Comment: I really don't know what is it i just used curl cause i just switched from C to Java but thanks i'll look it up

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With little changes to how you read the response you can do it like below:

```
JsonObject jsonObj = new JsonParser().parse(reader).getAsJsonObject()
jsonObj.get("code") ==> 200
jsonObj.get("lang") ==> "en-fa" 
jsonObj.get("text").getAsString()  ==> "سلام"
```

Comment: Glad to hear that. Can you please upvote the answer!!